# using python faker library but have import error

Tags: python, importerror, lib

I had this line in my code `from faker import Factory`and I had the error `ImportError: no module named faker`. So I looked up on Stack Overflow and pip installed fake-factory. It says installation successful but then when I ran the code again it gives me another import error:

```
ImportError: The ``fake-factory`` package is now called ``Faker``.

Please update your requirements.
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you pip install Faker? That's what the message seems to be implying.

Comment: I know nothing about Faker or Fake-Factory, but I'd bet they've got [a document somewhere](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fake-factory) that tells you what to do about the name change.  That was literally the first Google result for "[python fake-factory installation guide](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=python+fake-factory+installation+guide)".

Comment: Check if you used the correct `PIP version`. Most of distribs come with a python 2.x version and you might use a 3.x version. Control that you are using `pip3` and not `pip` then.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.

As the ImportError implies, you need to install Faker for this.

Move the directory in which your python library is installed and try this..

First uninstall fake-factory (I use pip) `pip uninstall fake-factory`

Then check if it is uninstalled using `pip freeze` and it should not be there

Then, proceed with installing Faker by `pip install Faker`

Now, try running that code again, it should work. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, It was working when I run `pip uninstall fake-factory`.